# How do I plot two horizontal lines at specific percentages of the first 5 minutes candle of each day in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot two horizontal lines in real time after the close of the first 5 minute candle.

Suppose the first 5 minute candle closes at 6000

I want the first line at 6000 + (0.25% of 6000) color is red
I want the second line at 6000 - (0.25% of 6000) color is green

I want this only for the current day. The lines should draw as soon as the first 5 minute candle closes.

I have been trying hline but it does not support variables
I also tried plot but it wants a series.
Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I had tried

```
    //@version=5
indicator("First 5-Minute Candle Lines", shorttitle="F5MCL", overlay=true)

// Check if the current bar is the first 5-minute candle of the day
isFirst5MinCandle = dayofweek != dayofweek[1]

// Calculate the close of the first 5-minute candle
first5MinClose = isFirst5MinCandle ? close : na

// Calculate the upper and lower lines
upperLine = first5MinClose + (first5MinClose * 0.25 / 100)
lowerLine = first5MinClose - (first5MinClose * 0.25 / 100)
//uL = (upperLine, upperLine)
//lL = (lowerLine, lowerLine)
// Plot the lines
//hline(upperLine,"Upper Line",color = color.red, linestyle = hline.style_solid, linewidth = 1)
//hline(lowerLine,"Lower Line",color = color.green, linestyle = hline.style_solid, linewidth = 1)
//plot(upperLine,"Upper Line",color = color.red,linewidth = 1)
//plot(lowerLine,"Lower Line",color = color.green,linewidth = 1)
plot(upperLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red)
plot(lowerLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: Post edited to include what I had tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for detect first 5m bar use `session.isfirstbar`, and use var variables to store upper and lower prices and change its values only on the first bar.

see the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("First 5-Minute Candle Lines", shorttitle="F5MCL", overlay=true)

// Calculate the close of the first 5-minute candle

var float upperLine = na
var float lowerLine = na


if session.isfirstbar
    // Calculate the upper and lower lines
    upperLine := close + (close * 0.25 / 100)
    lowerLine := close - (close * 0.25 / 100)

plot(upperLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red)
plot(lowerLine, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
```